# Conectar aplicación java mysql en la misma red lan

Tags: java, mysql

tengo desarrollada una aplicación en Java y funciona correctamente si lo ejecuto en la misma máquina donde tengo el servidor de mysql pero en otro equipo de la red no funciona, tengo una clase que es donde defino toda la lógica de la conexion:

```
public class Conexion {

    private final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    private final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.100.13:3306/";
    private final String DB = "dbsistema";
    private final String USER = "root";
    private final String PASSWORD = "Testament669";

    public Connection cadena;
    public static Conexion instancia; //Patrón singleton

    private Conexion() {
        this.cadena = null;
    }

    public Connection conectar() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            Class.forName(DRIVER);
            this.cadena = DriverManager.getConnection(URL + DB, USER, PASSWORD);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
            //Después del error cierro las conexiones
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return this.cadena;
    }

    public void desconectar() {
        try {
            this.cadena.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    //Se utiliza el patrón singleton
    public synchronized static Conexion getInstancia() {
        if (instancia == null) {
            instancia = new Conexion();
        }
        return instancia;
    }
}
```

De esa forma no funciona pero si cambio la linea: `"jdbc:mysql://192.168.100.13:3306/";` por `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";` si funciona pero solo de forma local.

El cuando ingreso el usuario y password en la aplicación el error es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tendrían alguna idea porque da ese error? Desde ya muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Un par de cosas... ese user y pass e ip no son reales no? Si lo son, ya tenemos que borrarlos. Despues, tu mysql acepta conexiones remotas? Tu ip es visible fuera de la red?

Comment: Hola tanto el user como el pass no son reales, lo puse asi para que sea mas especifico, No sabria decirte acepta conexiones remotas y la ip si es visible desde fuera de la red.

Comment: Betto lo primero que debes hacer es estar seguro que tanto la configuración de tu red es correcta y la PC donde ejecutas la aplicación pueder ver al servidor (a nivel de red) y luego configurar tu MySQL para que acepte conexiones desde esa PC. Esto es básicamente lo que te comenta @gbianchi y si no eres capaz de comprobar estas cosas díficilmente podremos ayudarte, porque como dice un amigo mía: "No hay dos redes iguales".

Comment: [Revisa este tutorial](https://kasunsiyambalapitiya.medium.com/how-to-setup-a-mysql-server-on-local-area-network-lan-c3c5012c7d6b). Tendrías que setear `bind-address` en el archivo de configuración de MySQL, indicando allí la dirección IP del equipo donde está instalada la BD. Si no tienes contratada IP fija tendrás que ingeniártela configurando un DNS dinámico o de otro modo.